# What medium could I use for a laser pointer to hit and illuminate an entire area behind it?

Tags: laser, optical-materials

I'm in the planning stages of making a fun project for my nephew which will allow a wood gun with a laser pointer attached to 'shoot' at a target area.  The target area will most likely be a piece of plywood with circles cut in it to act as the actual targets.  What material could I place in these circles (frosted glass?) that would make a laser fully illuminate the area behind it?  I plan on having a photo-diode/resistor of some sort behind each one encapsulated in a closed area.  The goal is that when the laser hits the medium which is for the most part flush with the plywood, the entire area behind it illuminates and can be detected with a microcontroller.

I'm open to alternatives if there are any ideas.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something like frosted glass would help diffuse the light, but my feeling is that the illuminated area will appear dim. If you're already planning on have some detection electronics built into your board, then why don't you simply include some LEDs and appropriate driver electronics to brightly light up  each target circle when it is hit rather than relying on the laser pointer itself to provide the target circle illumination?

Comment: My problem _is_ the detection elements of the circuit.  My detection needs to be based on a laser pointer hitting a round piece of plastic/glass medium and no matter where it's hit at, I can register a 'hit'.  I do plan on having extra circuitry inside to indicate a hit.  Any ideas on the material? I was planning to go buy a home depot this evening and look for some materials that might work well.

Comment: I see that Home Depot has clear as well as frosted acrylic sheets. You would really need to see that in person to determine if that is suitable for the amount of light scattering you need. You might also check out Tap Plastics, if there is a store in your area. They have a wide range of acrylic sheets of various thicknesses, finishes, and colors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sam, I appreciate it.  I'm going to bring a laser pointer to the store this evening and try a few out.

Comment: Your bigger issue will be to distinguish the laser pointer signal from the background. Are you modulating your laser? If not, I would strongly suggest you do.

Comment: You might do better with an ultrasonic beam, which is broader, and easily detected. Combine it with an LED flashlight for effect.

Answer (score 1):

Cover the 'target area' with a frosted sheet as the comments suggest; I would recommend placing the sensor inside a cylindrical, or better, spherical "can" and covering the inside of the can with similar reflective diffusing material.  Essentially what I'm describing is an "integrating sphere," which costs more than you want to know :-( . The idea is that the light from the source pretty much fills the container uniformly, guaranteeing that plenty of light hits the sensor itself.

Comment: Could I just take donated canned goods cans and use those since they are metal and will reflect the light?  I could even go further and wrap some half sphere mold of a toy in aluminum foil.  Do you think it's worth experimenting?

Comment: @user3000724  Sure, so long as the interior is reasonably shiny, give it a shot.